# Ambari Admin login hung with correct credentials, throws correct error with invalid credentials

Tags: mysql, centos, cloudera, ambari, hdp

I have setup Ambari 2.7.0 on Centos 7 server with Mysql 5.7.29 as backend.
All services are running fine, but when I try to login using `admin:admin` credential it seems to hang and shows following logs in `ambari-server.log` file:

```
2020-03-18 06:55:28,031  INFO [MessageBroker-1] WebSocketMessageBrokerStats:113 - WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannelpool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]

2020-03-18 06:55:28,678  INFO [MessageBroker-1] WebSocketMessageBrokerStats:113 - WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannelpool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

Interesting thing is, moment I enter invalid user or wrong password for `admin` user, it throws correct error `Invalid credentials` but on entering correct credentials, its hanging and logs above mentioned logs in `ambari-server.log` file.

Previously I used to see following logs in MySQL Log file:

```
[Note] Aborted connection 4 to db: '' user: '' host: '' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

As suggested on some questions, I increased `max_connections` to 400 and `max_allowed_packet` close to 2% of RAM available on server to `656MB`.

After increasing above mentioned configs, I dont see any `Error reading communication packets` in MySQL log file but I dont seem to get Ambari login working.

When I turn logging level for Ambari-Server to `debug` and enter random user it gives logs :

```
2020-03-18 11:24:16,116 DEBUG [ambari-client-thread-47] FilterChainProxy:325 - /api/v1/users/esrdf?fields=*,privileges/PrivilegeInfo/cluster_name,privileges/PrivilegeInfo/permission_name&_=1599955834198 at position 1 of 13 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
```

But when I enter correct credentials `admin:admin`, I dont see any API even being called within Logs. What could be the reason for this?

I tried debugging this using API calls, eg: `/api/v1/clusters`.
When I make the API call from the server itself, it gives correct response but when the API is made from local, it gives out `Recv failure: Connection was reset`

Can someone point me, where I could be going wrong?

Help Appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue. It was a VPN connectivity issue that was preventing login, Ambari UI could be accessed but not login. 
Login works when connected to a machine on same network.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what may be happening is that once you deploy to service all your paths are a little off, so lets say you have link that says  [home](/home)  it will work on local but will not work on server because your application URL is now host:8080/appName/ and when you refer to anything with /home instead of taking you to host:8080/appName/home it will take you to host:8080/home, at which point its a broken url.